# Unable to pass the URL from properties file to Page Object

Tags: java, selenium, maven, driver

I'm trying to build my first framework from scratch, it's based on Selenium Webdriver with Cucumber and Java. I created config.properties with the URL stored, then I created PropertiesFile class where I set chromedriver and get the URL, below is the code:

```
    package config;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertiesFile {

    private static String url;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("./src/main/java/config/config.properties");

        FileInputStream fileInput = null;
        try {
            fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        try {
            prop.load(fileInput);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./integers/drivers/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
        System.out.println("url ::" + prop.getProperty("url"));

        url = prop.getProperty("url");
    }

    public static String getURL() {
        return url;
    }
}
```

I'd like to pass the same URL to Page Object class, however I got a bit stuck. I'm getting the error on super(driver, wait) and also driver.get(baseURL) returns the error bc of the lack of local variable.

```
package page_objects;
import config.PropertiesFile;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class addingFormPage {

    public addingFormPage (WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait) {
        super(driver, wait);
    }

    String baseURL = PropertiesFile.getURL();

    public void openHome (){
        driver.get(baseURL);
```

Could anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Can you share the error you're getting?

Comment: @Mureinik so on super(driver, wait) the error is 'Object()' in 'java.lang.Object' cannot be applied to '(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver, org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait)' and regarding openHome method the error is related to lack of the local variable 'driver', field 'driver' in addingFormPage or parameter 'driver' (these are the solutions proposed by IntelliJ). However I don't really know how to create it as driver was set up in PropertiesFile class.